# PHPMailer - HTML content getting blocked

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer

I'm having trouble trying to send out a HTML email. 
I can:

- Connect to the server fine with SMTP and SSL
- I can send a simple HTML email fine

But anything that resembles what I would call "normal" HTML content gets blocked EVERY TIME!

Anyone suggest anything to try? I don't see anything wrong with what I've done, but obvs there's something there...

So this code gets blocked for me:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "xxxx";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "xxx";
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->setFrom('xxx', 'Me');
$mail->addReplyTo('xxx', 'Me');

$mail->addAddress('xxx@me.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Here come the bastards';
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->msgHTML('
  <html>
    <body>
      <table style="width: 100%;background-color: #60bb98;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://mystorymycontent.com/wp-content/themes/MSMC/img/logo-new.gif" />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>HELLO EVERYONEZZZ
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </body>
  </html>
');

$mail->AltBody = 'Heres all the copy from the HTML verison of the email. Theres a few lines about things and that';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: What you mean "blocked"? You don't get email or content is escaped?

Comment: can you explain what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PHPMailer to send HTML mails and I had to do this :

```
$mail->IsHTML();
```

From the doc :

> Before sending this out, we have to modify the PHPMailer object to
>   indicate that the message should be interpreted as HTML.
>   Technically-speaking, the message body has to be set up as
>   multipart/alternative. This is done with: $mail->IsHTML(true);

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @FLX but in the phpmailer example it's written this way

```
$email ->IsHTML();
```

not

```
$mail ->IsHTML();
```

or the variable with you create the instance.

```
$VARIABLE = new PHPMailer();
.
.
.
.
$VARIABLE ->IsHTML();
```

it's just a suggestion